# All my nav links are highlighted as active in Neve Theme - Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using the Neve theme to build a custom WP theme. It is a one-pager.

So all nav links in the menu are custom links, linking to a section within the home page.

I first tried to make them relative links e.g. #service but then the mobile menu would not close after clicking them. After reading a bit online I found the solution to make them aboslute links e.g.
mydomain.com/#service

Now my mobile menu does close but all nav items are marked as active having this class

'current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home'

How do I find a workaround or what is in general the best way to handle this to only have the Home link active and not the rest?

Thanks in advance.

-Gerd

Comment: If it's a onepager just add a custom css class to the home link and add the active style to that then remove any styling from `.current-menu-item`

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks to Nico for pointing me in the right direction.

I wanted to post this here in a little more detail for everyone, who might have a similar issue.

1. I cleared all the formatting from the WP class that was assigned to all navigation link.
2. I created my own active class, called 'my-active'
3. I wrote the following jQuery code to add it when a nav item is clicked and take it away from the previos nav item (this might not be ideal code, since I am not a professional coder, but it works):

   ```
   (function ($) {
      $(document).ready(function () {


      $('nav ul li:nth-child(1) a').addClass('my-active');

      $('nav ul li a').on('click', function(){

         $('nav ul li a').removeClass('my-active');
         $(this).addClass('my-active');
   });

   });
   ```

   })(jQuery);